# Git hangs on pushing to

Tags: git

I'm trying to push my code on GitHub without success. I'm connected to my VPS ( CentOs 8 ) through SSH.

```
# git push -v
Pushing to https://github.com/xxx/epAPIv2
```

After 20min, nothing changed. I think something is blocking the connection.

```
# GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 140.82.121.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (140.82.121.3) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*  start date: Mar 25 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 30 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "github.com" matched cert's "github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert, Inc.; CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /xxx/epAPIv2/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: git/2.27.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; sandbox
< Content-Length: 21
< www-authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: E35A:E392:17A3EF4:18D5999:618C823E
< 
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
```

Stucks again.
I tried to disable my firewall, make sure I have no proxy, re-install git, every solution I can find on SO, ... no more idea. It used to work on this VPS.

Thanks

Comment: How are you caching your credentials? Are you using a token? (since password is no longer authorized)

Comment: Yes, I think it uses a token.

Comment: What does `git config --global credential.helper` returns on your VPS? And `git version`?

Comment: `git config --global credential.helper` return nothing
`# git version : git version 2.27.0` Git is up to date
`
# yum update git
Last metadata expiration check: 0:32:06 ago on Thu 11 Nov 2021 09:29:32 PM PST.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
`

Comment: Do you have Git LFS activated? (do you see lfs anywhere in your `local repo/.git/config` file?) Or do you have a ~/.netrc with in it an old token?

Answer (score 1):

One reason is because Git would read the `~/.netrc`, which could include an old token.

The other is because the repository is using [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), and as [commented here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4060#issuecomment-596782878) by [brian m. carlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204)

> The reason you're seeing this is that Git LFS needs credentials in addition to Git, and there's no way to pass these credentials along from Git to Git LFS.
> If you want to avoid this, then you'll need to use a `credential helper`.
> You can run `git config --global credential.helper cache` to use the cache credential helper which will cache the credentials for about five minutes, or if you're on a Linux system with a desktop environment, you can use the `libsecret` credential helper if it's available (or, on Debian and Ubuntu, you can copy `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/` somewhere else and then build it after installing the `libsecret-1-dev` package).
>
> You're likely seeing the window because either `core.askpass` is set somewhere in your config or because `GIT_ASKPASS` or `SSH_ASKPASS` is set in the environment. Those are the places we look for an `askpass` helper.

Comment: Thanks! for your answer I tried everything without success. Today, everything worked! I have no idea what was wrong. Maybe an old token.

Comment: @Sylvain Glad to know it is working!